# MongoDB - Lost connection to the database after rebooting the VPS

Tags: php, mongodb, codeigniter

I am using Digital Ocean and rebooted my VPS and now my app won't start.

At first it said it lost connection to my database and now it's just a white screen. I don't know what to do from here.

Here is the message:

```
Unable to connect to MongoDB: Failed to connect to: localhost:27017: Remote server has closed the connection
```

The site is a Codeigniter.

[The Site](http://dev.teachtomarket.com)

If I run `mongod` then I get this (not that I should need to run this):

```
Tue Oct 28 19:42:45.031 [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=1240 port=27017 dbpath=/data/db/ 64-bit host=lucrum
Tue Oct 28 19:42:45.031 [initandlisten] db version v2.4.8
Tue Oct 28 19:42:45.031 [initandlisten] git version: a350fc38922fbda2cec8d5dd842237b904eafc14
Tue Oct 28 19:42:45.032 [initandlisten] build info: Linux ip-10-2-29-40 2.6.21.7-2.ec2.v1.2.fc8xen #1 SMP Fri Nov 20 17:48:28 EST 2009 x86_64 BOOST_LIB_VERSION=1_49
Tue Oct 28 19:42:45.032 [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
Tue Oct 28 19:42:45.032 [initandlisten] options: {}
Tue Oct 28 19:42:45.041 [initandlisten] journal dir=/data/db/journal
Tue Oct 28 19:42:45.042 [initandlisten] recover : no journal files present, no recovery needed
Tue Oct 28 19:42:45.166 [initandlisten] ERROR: listen(): bind() failed errno:98 Address already in use for socket: 0.0.0.0:27017
Tue Oct 28 19:42:45.166 [initandlisten] ERROR:   addr already in use
Tue Oct 28 19:42:45.167 [initandlisten] now exiting
Tue Oct 28 19:42:45.167 dbexit: 
Tue Oct 28 19:42:45.167 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close listening sockets...
Tue Oct 28 19:42:45.167 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to flush diaglog...
Tue Oct 28 19:42:45.168 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close sockets...
Tue Oct 28 19:42:45.168 [initandlisten] shutdown: waiting for fs preallocator...
Tue Oct 28 19:42:45.168 [initandlisten] shutdown: lock for final commit...
Tue Oct 28 19:42:45.168 [initandlisten] shutdown: final commit...
Tue Oct 28 19:42:45.168 [websvr] ERROR: listen(): bind() failed errno:98 Address already in use for socket: 0.0.0.0:28017
Tue Oct 28 19:42:45.169 [websvr] ERROR:   addr already in use
Tue Oct 28 19:42:45.172 [initandlisten] shutdown: closing all files...
Tue Oct 28 19:42:45.173 [initandlisten] closeAllFiles() finished
Tue Oct 28 19:42:45.173 [initandlisten] journalCleanup...
Tue Oct 28 19:42:45.173 [initandlisten] removeJournalFiles
Tue Oct 28 19:42:45.174 [initandlisten] shutdown: removing fs lock...
Tue Oct 28 19:42:45.174 dbexit: really exiting now
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is mighty embarrassing but I can laugh at myself. I ended up doing a rollback and fixed the issue, then replaced all of my application with new files and the issue came back. So I ended up looking into one of my model files and found this ...

```
var $sessionArray = arsray();
```

Nothing like a good `arsray` to ruin your day!